# Fiddler shows Chinese as question marks

Tags: c#, asp.net, fiddler, multilingual

I am testing a webservice using c# and fiddler. My database has Chinese text stored..within my debugger i can see the chinese text stored into a c# variable FINE, however when I post the REQUEST using c# and debug it in fiddler, fiddler shows the text as Question Marks (???). why is that? hence my webservice is also seeing it as ????.

here is my code sample

```
public confirmationStatus Send(string phoneNumber, string text)
{

    messages_send model = new messages_send() { contacts = new List<string>() { phoneNumber }, text=text };
    string url = this.setupUrl();
    string dataToSend = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);

    var cli = new WebClient();
    cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
    string response = cli.UploadString(url, dataToSend);

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<confirmationStatus>(response);

}
```

and this is how Fiddler sees it.

```
POST https://api.***.com/v1/messages? HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.**.com
Content-Length: 1061
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"contacts":["+1*****9"],"text":"**??HME??????** John,??? 01-01-0001 ???? 12:00 AM ? 12:00 AM? ????????????????????: Link: https://www.****.com/timesheets/?v=0 .Text STOP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "}
```

Comment: So, the usual thing here is encoding differences. You may wish to change the Content-Type header to include the charset desired (e.g., `application/json; charset=utf-8").

Comment: I tried it but still no luck.

Comment: At what point did you capture this? Is this the request as it is sent (ie. a problem with the client) or is this the response from the server (so an issue with the server code or an incorrect header)?

Comment: It may be that the charset is not UTF-8; that was just an example. You'll need to determine what encoding you're using/should be using. It might be Fiddler for that matter; I suggest using something like Postman or a browser's network tools.

Comment: it s a WinForm Application. I am sending the request using VISUAL STUDIO, browser tools wont really help. WebService Support tells me to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was, .NET encodes strings to UTF-16 by default. hence Fiddler and my webservice was unable to encode it properly and showing question marks.

Changing the ContentType of HTTP Headers did not do the trick. I changed the encoding of WebClient object and it worked.

Hence the Answer for me was...

> ```
>         var cli = new WebClient();
>         cli.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
> ```

in .NET we can change the encoding for streams, so I believe thats why it worked.